# How to change tintColor bar button item when I share on Telegram?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change bar button item when I share text.

My code is the following:

```
 let color = UIColor.red
    let newFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 16.0)!
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.classForCoder() as! UIAppearanceContainer.Type]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSFontAttributeName: newFont], for: .normal)
```

that's what happened:
[image]

I just changed the button "Cancel".
How can I change tintColor of a "Send" bar button?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = .red
```